# Multidimentional data pass to View page in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Recently I face a problem to do a project.

The controller page

```
 if ($result -> num_rows () ==1) {
        $info['stu_data']=array();
        $i=0;
        $rs= $this -> db -> query ($this -> User_model -> view_action());
        if ($rs -> num_rows() > 0) {
          foreach ($rs -> result() as $rows) {
            $info [$i]['stu_name'] = $rows -> stu_name;
            $info [$i]['username'] = $rows -> username ;
            $info [$i]['roll'] = $rows -> roll ;
            $info [$i]['password'] = $rows -> password ;
            $info [$i]['first'] = $rows -> first;
            $info [$i]['second'] = $rows -> second ;
            $info [$i]['third'] = $rows -> third;
            $info [$i]['fourth'] = $rows -> fourth;
            $info [$i]['fifth'] = $rows -> fifth ;
            $i++;

          }

        }

        //$data['data']=$this -> User_model -> view_action();
        //print_r($info);
       $this -> load -> view ('add',$info);
    }
```

And the View page is

```
<?php
var_dump($stu_data); 
?>
```

But I got Noting in the add.php page. But the value of $info variable at Controller page will be ok.

Please solve this problem.

Comment: `$info['stu_data']=array();` as a result `$stu_data` is equal empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$info['stu_data']` is **not populated** by your fetch method!

Try out `$info ['stu_data']` instead of just `$info` when fetching your results from your query.

Furthermore as [Rocket Hazmat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) mentioned, you can simplify your current fetch process by not using a helper variable (`[$i]` in your case) and creating an array on the fly.

---

**Optimized code**

```
if ($rs -> num_rows() > 0) {
      foreach ($rs -> result() as $rows) {
        $info['stu_data'][] = array('stu_name' => $rows -> stu_name, 'username' => $rows -> username, 
        'roll' => $rows -> roll, 'password' = $rows -> password, 'first' => $rows -> first,
        'second' => $rows -> second, 'third' => $rows -> third, 'fourth' => $rows -> fourth, 
        'fifth' => $rows -> fifth);
      }
```

Comment: There's no reason to be using `$i` here at all.  You could just do `$info['stu_data'][] = array('stu_name' => $rows->stu_name, ...);`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for passing data to view page. It is simple to use and also simple to understand.

```
if ($result -> num_rows () ==1) {
    $i=0;
    $rs= $this -> db -> query ($this -> User_model -> view_action());
    if ($rs -> num_rows() > 0) {
      foreach ($rs -> result() as $rows) {
        $data['stu_name'] = $rows -> stu_name;
        $data['username'] = $rows -> username ;
        $data['roll'] = $rows -> roll ;
        $data['password'] = $rows -> password ;
        $data['first'] = $rows -> first;
        $data['second'] = $rows -> second ;
        $data['third'] = $rows -> third;
        $data['fourth'] = $rows -> fourth;
        $data['fifth'] = $rows -> fifth ;
        $info['stu_data'][$i]=$data;
        $i++;
      }

    }

    //$data['data']=$this -> User_model -> view_action();
    //print_r($info);
   $this -> load -> view ('add',$info);
}
```

I hope you will get your solution.